# HQL in operator and parameters

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm

There is need for quering NHibernate for several instances of the entity. I've tried following code, but it failed with wired NRE indepth of NHibernate.

```
var query = NHibernateSession.CreateQuery("from User u where u.id in (:ids)");
query.SetParameterList("ids", new Guid[]);
query.ToList();
```

It looks like common problem - any suggestions?

*Update* This only occurs if array is empty - question closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:ids would be an empty Guid array, wouldn't it? You're asking NHibernate to give you users where the id is inside a non-initialized array of Guid.

Comment: Yes, I know it. It's just example. Replace
new Guid[]
by
new [] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(),Guid.NewGuid() }

Comment: But Guid is supposed to give you that, unique ids. You're asking for ids on a database that are the same that some new unique ids. If I'm not getting it, tell me and I'll delete this answer ;)

Comment: You're not getting it, but you are right :) Error occurs only on empty array. I've just tested it on empty DB.